# How can I change the default battle keys in Star Control II?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, dosbox, star-control-2

I got an original copy of Star Control II and I am playing it under DOSBox in my Windows 7. It all works beautifully.

However, the game come with a file named "keys.exe" which does affect the keys in Super Melee, but it does not affect the keys in the game itself: it seems to be "stuck" on <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> only. (ordinary shot and special shot)

Anybody have an idea? Maybe it's something with the DOSBox and the way it maps the keys? Although it's not likely, as in the Super Melee which also runs under DOSBox it works fine.

Comment: Not a fix, but you could play The Ur-Quan Masters instead: http://sc2.sourceforge.net/ It's a modernized free version of the game.

Comment: @Maardvark thanks, the last sentence means there is separate game arriving in the package that has the same battle system, and in that game changing the keys is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not re-map the keys in DOSBox itself?  I believe this may change your keyboard mappings for text entry as well, but there are very few (if any) places in SC2/UQM where text entry is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Interesting idea, didn't occur to me it's possible - will give it a try soon. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Let me know how it goes.  I remember seeing at one point that it was possible, but when I tried looking it up last night I came up dry.  I'm interested in doing it for another game myself.

Comment: I tried mapping SPACE to M and it said "Mapper file saved" but it didn't affect the game keys at all, plus I couldn't find any mapper file anywhere.. ideas? :-/

Comment: How'd you do that mapping?  I haven't dinked around enough yet to figure out where that would be.

Comment: Activated DOSBOX directly to get its command line in there pressed CTRL+F1 to reach the mapping screen. In there you can select a key then bind it to different key.